# Delete engine for deeply nested linked structure

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, multithreading

The background is the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634394/nested-shared-ptr-destruction-causes-stack-overflow. To summarize, for a data structure that looks like:

```
// A node in a singly linked list.
struct Node {
    int head;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> tail;
};
```

If the list grows too long, a stack overflow might occur in the destructor of `Node` due to recursive destructions of the `shared_ptr`s. I'm implementing a thread-safe version of the delete engine proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36635668/3234803.

There are three simple classes involved: `SpinLock`, `ConcurrentQueue`, and `DeleteEngine`.

The `SpinLock` class implements the C++ Lockable interface with a `std::atomic_flag`:

```
class SpinLock {
public:
    void lock()
    { while (lock_.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire) {} }

    bool try_lock() // Not camel-case to be compatible with C++ Lockable interface
    { return !lock_.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire); }

    void unlock()
    { lock_.clear(std::memory_order_release); }

private:
    std::atomic_flag lock_ = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
};
```

The `ConcurrentQueue` class implements a multiple-producer-single-consumer queue that supports thread-safe `enqueue` and `tryDequeue`:

```
template<typename T>
class ConcurrentQueue {
public:
    void enqueue(T item)
    {
        std::lock_guard<SpinLock> lk(lock_);
        queue_.emplace_back(std::move(item));
    }

    bool tryDequeue(T &item)
    {
        std::lock_guard<SpinLock> lk(lock_);
        if (queue_.empty()) {
            return false;
        }
        item = std::move(queue_.front());
        queue_.pop_front();
        return true;
    }

private:
    std::deque<T> queue_;
    SpinLock lock_;
};
```

The `DeleteEngine` class implements the delete engine proposed in the answer aforementioned:

```
template<typename T>
class DeleteEngine {
public:
    ~DeleteEngine()
    {
        std::lock_guard<SpinLock> lk(deleting_);
        deleteAll();
    }

    void enqueue(T *p)
    {
        queue_.enqueue(p);
        if (deleting_.try_lock()) {
            std::lock_guard<SpinLock> lk(deleting_, std::adopt_lock);
            deleteAll();
        }
    }

private:
    void deleteAll()
    {
        T *p = nullptr;
        while (queue_.tryDequeue(p)) {
            delete p;
        }
    }

    ConcurrentQueue<T *> queue_;
    SpinLock deleting_;
};
```

Now in the deleter of a `shared_ptr<Node>`, we will hand the raw pointer to a `DeleteEngine<Node>` instead of directly `delete`ing it. A recursive `delete` can handle up to about 10000 nodes, while this method can handle an arbitrarily large number of nodes.

The above code is only a prototype, but I'm particularly concerned about the performance of this implementation: (1) Most of the time the `Node` class would be used in a single-threaded environment; (2) Occasionally it might be used in highly concurrent applications, e.g. a web server that constantly creates and destroys objects.

Comment: Interesting! I wouldn't worry about contention, the overhead of the locking is going to be eclipsed by the time spent freeing memory. But there is a race, since even if the lock is already taken when you enter `DeleteEngine::enqueue`, there's no guarantee that queued pointer will be seen by `deleteAll` before the lock is released (or even before `deleteAll` returns).

Comment: @Cameron Can you elaborate further? The goal of the delete engine is to allow multiple threads to enqueue at the same time, but only one thread can delete (until the queue is empty, after which another thread can take over).

Comment: Right. Say thread A calls `DeleteEngine::enqueue` and takes the lock, then starts deleting. Thread B now calls `enqueue` as well. Before it enqueues, though, `deleteAll` on thread A returns (but the lock is not released yet). Thread B then enqueues and sees the lock is still taken, so it returns. Thread A then releases the lock. The result: There is still an item in the queue that will not be deleted until the next call to `deleteAll`.

Comment: This is just one example, there's more subtle ones along the same lines where the element is enqueued by the second thread, but the thread in deleteAll doesn't see it right away (because you're using acquire/release and not sequential consistency), with the same end result. If you want to avoid these kind of races, you'll have to synchronize on a single variable (not the queue and the lock separately), e.g. a counter of the number of things in the queue. It would be simpler (and likely faster) to have one deleter per thread.

Comment: Oh, and I just realized: Using acquire/release in the lock for the queue is not enough. A thread could enqueue, and release the lock, then another thread could acquire the lock but not yet synchronize with the release (the memory effects aren't yet visible on its CPU core), which would lead to corruption of the queue. This should be reproducible empirically with a high-contention test. EDIT: Ah, wait, I take that back. That can't happen because the atomic flag value itself was necessarily propagated to the thread acquiring the lock, and so it *must* synchronize with the previous release.

Comment: @Cameron Ah, that's subtle! The usual usage will be that one list owns one deleter (in the form of a `std::shared_ptr`), so if the whole list is destructed so will the deleter be, consequently destructing everything in  `~DeleteEngine()`. Can you give a simple example of the counter of number of things you mentioned? I'm a little bit unsure how to do that.

Comment: If there's one deleter per list, surely you don't need it to be thread safe? Counter: The idea is to centralize all state-change decisions on a single atomic variable (because two independently atomic things is not enough, as you can see). Instead of using a lock in the deleter, track the number of things to be deleted. Increment it atomically just after enqueueing with a FAA. If it was 0, start deleting. When deleting, keep going (decrementing the count after each delete) until the count hits 0. This way you can't leak elements -- each time the count restarts from 0 someone deletes.

Comment: @Cameron Well, the list is designed to allow sharing between multiple threads, so I'm not sure if the destructors won't be invoked on different threads in some weird situation. About the counter variable, do you think using a lock to protect the deque's `size()` method is enough?

Comment: The deque would still need the lock. But the counter would provide synchronization between the queue (number of elements) and the deleter (whether it's deleting or not) at the same time.

Comment: @Cameron I'm not entirely sure how a counter can replace the `deleting_` flag currently used in my code. How can I know from a counter whether the delete is in progress?

Comment: You can't, exactly. But you can know when to start a new delete (each time it gets incremented from 0). With `deleting`, you only know whether someone is in the critical section or not. With a counter, you know whether there is anything to delete or not.

Comment: @Cameron So how do I prevent a second delete process when something is enqueued in the middle of an ongoing delete?

Comment: The count won't be zero at that point; it only falls to zero after the queue is emptied.

Answer (score 2):

To address the locking overhead in the single-threaded case, my first advice is (as with all performance questions) to **measure** before optimising!  It's likely that the locking overhead is tiny compared to the queue's memory management.

If you really find you need to streamline the locking, then you'll probably want to have two versions of the engine.  The simplest way to do that is probably to add a boolean parameter to the template, and then use `if constexpr` at the points where the code differs.  Or perhaps make the lock type a template parameter, and supply a no-op lock when creating the single-thread version.